# HOOPS: 2d pdf driver not created

Tags: pdf-generation, hoops

I am fairly new to HOOPS, so sorry if the question is dumb.

I am trying to export my scene as a 2D pdf. It does not work, because /driver/pdf segment does not exist. According to [documentation](http://docs.techsoft3d.com/visualize/3df/latest/build/general/device_guide.html), PDF is supported on all platforms (so far I am testing on Windows 7, 64bit), however I only see these driver segments existing:

```
/driver/2ddriver
/driver/3ddriver
/driver/image
/driver/msw
/driver/null
/driver/opengl
/driver/opengl2
```

i.e. a number of drivers that are supposed to be supported on all platforms do not exist, e.g. postscript, printf etc.

I presume something is wrong with my HOOPS installation, but what?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! :)

My /bin/ was missing pdf2120_x64.hdi - once I added it, driver got magically created and pdf export worked.

The .hdi file is actually a renamed .dll and can be viewed in dependency walker.